# Mirror API - Remove time from right corner

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is there a way to remove the time from the lower right corner of cards?   In the case of pinned cards, it does not always make sense to show how long the card has been there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not yet possible through the API, please file a feature request on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: This has been filed as https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=210